# Jquery Validation not working in ASP MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-validation

I am trying to use jquery validation in my ASP MVC project however the validation doesn't seems to work . I have reference to jquery.validate.js file and i have also set unobstructive javascript false but still when button gets clicked, i don't see any error message showing up in my form. Currently the rules is just for required field but eventually im planning to use more complex validation.

Any suggestions what am I missing?

Here is my setup:

```
BundleConfig.cs :     
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include("~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

_Layout.cshtml
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

Model:
public class SearchViewModel
{
   public string FirstName {get; set;}
   public string LastName  {get; set;}
}


Search.cshtml
@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchClient", "Client", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "clientSearchForm", @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
HtmlHelper.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled = false;
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="lblSid" class="control-label col-xs-5">First Name</label>
                <div class="col-xs-7">                    
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="lblMinuteMissing" class="control-label col-xs-5">Last Name</label>
                <div class="col-xs-7">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-5">
                    <button type="button" id="btnSearch" class="btn btn-success"> <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Search</button>
                </div>                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><br /> 
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#clientSearchForm").validate({            
            rules: {
                FirstName: {
                    required: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                FirstName: {
                    required: 'Please enter FirstName'
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>

Web.config:
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

Comment: have you provided `name` attribute in both the fields?

Comment: Validation rules can be added to the model (see `[Required]` anotation), instead of as a script in the view. When defined in the model it will run validation at client and server side. If you manually do it in the view then you'll need to validate again at server for security reasons. What you're trying to do doesn't require code. Just adding annotations to the model. That even supports regular expressions. If you want to use data annotations make sure you have `<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />` and UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled needs to be true.

Comment: @PankajMakwana while using Html.EditorFor it does add name attribute.

Comment: @derloopkat i do understand for required validation but as i mentioned in my question, i will eventually add complex validation like either one of the textboxes needs to have value, if it has a value it cannot be less than 2 characters. The required field validation is just to test out if i can use jquery validaton in my project. both keys ClientValidatonEnabled and UnobstrusiveJavascriptEnabled are set true in web.config

Comment: @sanjeevshrestha, for length use `[StringLength(2)]`. In addition, data annotations can run regex for validating complex pattern. If internet browser has javascript disable the error can still be detected by checking ModelState.IsValid at server side.

Comment: You want to know why jQuery/JavaScript is not working as expected without showing us any of the ***RENDERED*** HTML markup.  Check your console for errors.  Use the `debug` option of the plugin and check your console again.  Do you have `name` attributes that match the names you're using within the `rules` object?  Do you have a `form` that matches the jQuery selector in your JavaScript?  These are things we could eliminate if you showed the rendered HTML markup.